# Dockerized ROS2 development environment

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a sandboxed development environment for ROS2? (The/one ROS1 equivalent: [rosdocked](https://github.com/jbohren/rosdocked) )

I identified 3 different use cases with potentially different docker Images:

- ROS2 core package development
- ROS2 application development
- ROS2 + ROS1 application development

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282229/dockerized-ros2-development-environment/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the first 2 use cases (ROS2 core package development, ROS2 application development) [this Dockerfile from the official docker image repo](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/master/ros2/source/source/Dockerfile) can be used as base.

A first useable draft can be found [here](https://github.com/fkromer/ros2-devenv). (Is sufficient for me right now.)

---

Originally posted by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) with karma: 468 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0